# Error: [ngModel:numfmt] Expected `1` to be a number angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm beginner in Angular.js.

I'm trying to generate a dynamic form on `angular.js` app by fetching data from `mongodb`. I've stored imported data on mongodb through excel sheet so that's why all the `JSON` values are getting stored in `String` format.

To tackle that issue I'm generating form dynamically by checking value of JSON object.

Ex: If value contains number ("123456") then I'll display `input type="number"`, if value contains email then `input type="email"`, value contains dob then `datepicker` and so on..

Following is my template code:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="(key,value) in providerList"  ng-if="!$first">                    
   <label>{{key.replace("_", " ") | uppercase}}</label>
   <div ng-if="providerList[key].length > 100">
   <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="providerList[key]"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div ng-if="providerList[key].length < 100 && !isNumeric(providerList[key]) && !checkEmail(providerList[key])">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id='datepicker' ng-model="providerList[key]">        
   </div>

   <div ng-if="isNumeric(providerList[key])">                        
   <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="providerList[key]">        
   </div>

   <div ng-if="checkEmail(providerList[key])">                        
   <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="providerList[key]">        
   </div>
</div>
```

Here's my controller:

```
    $scope.isNumeric = function (data) {

                if (isNaN(data)) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }

//                if (/^\d+$/.test(data)) {
//                    return true;
//                } else {
//                    return false;
//                }
            };

            $scope.checkEmail = function (email) {
                var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
                return re.test(email);
            };
```

Here whenever `isNumeric` function getting called its showing following error on console:

```
Error: [ngModel:numfmt] Expected `1` to be a number
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ngModel/numfmt?p0=1
minErr/<@http://localhost:1000/js/vendor/angular/angular.js:68:12
numberInputType/<@http://localhost:1000/js/vendor/angular/angular.js:21977:1
ngModelWatch@http://localhost:1000/js/vendor/angular/angular.js:25489:21
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:1000/js/vendor/angular/angular.js:15888:34
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:1000/js/vendor/angular/angular.js:16160:13
done@http://localhost:1000/js/vendor/angular/angular.js:10589:36
completeRequest@http://localhost:1000/js/vendor/angular/angular.js:10787:7
requestLoaded@http://localhost:1000/js/vendor/angular/angular.js:10728:1


return logFn.apply(console, args);

angular.js (line 12520)
Error: [ngModel:numfmt] Expected `1234567890` to be a number
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ngModel/numfmt?p0=1234567890
minErr/<@http://localhost:1000/js/vendor/angular/angular.js:68:12
numberInputType/<@http://localhost:1000/js/vendor/angular/angular.js:21977:1
ngModelWatch@http://localhost:1000/js/vendor/angular/angular.js:25489:21
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:1000/js/vendor/angular/angular.js:15888:34
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:1000/js/vendor/angular/angular.js:16160:13
done@http://localhost:1000/js/vendor/angular/angular.js:10589:36
completeRequest@http://localhost:1000/js/vendor/angular/angular.js:10787:7
```

Same way I'm calling function for email checking `checkEmail` and its working perfectly fine so what's the issue with `isNumeric` function.

Comment: you need to parse value to Int/Float before assigning in numeric case

Comment: I tried that but its not working

Comment: Check http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ngModel/numfmt?p0=1234567890 . They given example to solve the issue

Comment: In this case they are validating numbers but here I want to check string whether string contains number or character and based on that I want to populate `input type`

Comment: Just try using the directive they given in example or create plunkr  . Hopefully it will work for you

Comment: @Ajinder Singh: Can u please give an example how can I do this. Bcoz I don't have much idea about directives in Angular

Comment: Do some study about directives in angular or create a plunkr for your problem.

Answer (score 7):

```
angular.module('numfmt-error-module', [])

.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.typeOf = function(value) {
    return typeof value;
  };
})

.directive('stringToNumber', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        return '' + value;
      });
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        return parseFloat(value);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And then, use 'string-to-number' on respective input.

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/numfmt

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. FYI: You don't need the first .run().

Answer (score 5):

Issue is with form input type='number' and JSON string is passed to the model.

You need to parse all numbers in controller (as soons as response is received from $http call) before assigning to the model or before opening the form

Answer (score 0):

your model

> **providerList[key]**

should contain 1 as number but it must have been "1" which is string, so this error is coming.

change the model values to numbers.